# Brownian Motions, Integrals, and Orthonormal Functions

Tags: brownian-motion, orthogonality, eigenfunctions, wiener-measure

I am out of my element with a topic I am working on.  I think I have dwindled down the part I am stuck on to the following.

If $\phi_n(t)$  is a sequence of orthonormal (eigenfunctions) functions and $B(t)$ is a standard Brownian Motion (Weiner Process), then

$$\psi_n =\int^c_0 \phi_n(t) dB(t)$$

where

$$\psi_n \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, 1).$$

Now, I believe I have seen this result before where $c=1$. I am hoping that what I have above is true for an arbitrary positive $c$ that can be greater than one.  If so, where/how can I find information that this is true? Much appreciated!

Comment: It does not matter what kind of function $\phi_n(t)$ is. It is well-known in the theory of stochastic integrals w.r.t. to the W$\color{red}{ie}$ner  process that $\phi_n$ is normal with mean zero and variance $\int_0^c\phi_n^2(t)\,dt$. This should be mentioned in every book about stochastic calculus. For example Karatzas & Shreve *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*.

Comment: Regarding $\psi_n \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, 1).$ This is probably true. The standard deviation follows from the formula I mentioned in the last comment assuming that the functions $\phi_n$ are *normed* on $[0,c]$. Their orthogonality on $[0,c]$ implies the uncorrelatedness of $\psi_n$ and $\psi_m$ with $n\not=m$. Hence indepence.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!